# Match Multiple Columns In Two Files - Output Only Those That Match Fully

Tags: python, join, awk

File 1:

```
1075908|2178412|brown_eyeshorty@att.net|Claude|Desmangles
175908|2178412|naim.kazi@webtv.net|Naim|Kazi
175972|212946872418|gil_maynard@hotmail.com|Munster|Herman
175972|212946872418|meghanj4@lycos.com|Meghan|Judge
175972|212946872418|quenchia@gmail.com|Anna|Balint
176046|255875|keion@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
176046|255875|keion112@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
176086|2480881|lourdsneil@gmail.com|Lourds|Herman
```

File 2:

```
89129090|Sadiq|Islam
212946872418|Anna|Balint
255875|Charlene|Johnson
89234902|Bob|Brown
09123789|Fabio|Vanetti
```

I would like to extract lines where ALL values match on the following basis:

- Column 2 in File 1 matches with Column 1 in File 2.
- Column 4 in File 1 matches with Column 2 in File 2.
- Column 5 in File 1 matches with Column 3 in File 2.

The expected output for the example is:

```
175972|212946872418|quenchia@gmail.com|Anna|Balint
176046|255875|keion@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
176046|255875|keion112@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
```

The two inputs I'm working with are both very large (11Gb and 3Gb respectively).

The only potential (messy) workaround I can think of is to combine the values to be joined into a single additional column and then use Join (I'm very new to this).

Comment: Hello taosim, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure what to try. I know I can match based on join, but only use a single value that's been sorted. Apologies I'm quite new to this.

Comment: You can try with `pandas`. Create two `dataframes` and use joins. If you face any difficulty after trying, Please paste that code here. We will help you! If you any queries on this, feel free to ask.

Comment: @taosim, your expected output looks like wrong, i see no reason why `176046|255875|keion112@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson` would not be present.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it.

Comment: @taosim I can give you pandas solution! Is there any problem in using `pandas` python library?

Comment: @shaikmoeed perhaps the memory usage (reading 11gb+3 on pandas may requires a lot of memory)

Comment: @taoism wrt `I'm not really sure what to try. ... I'm quite new to this.` - didn't you get **any** clues from your last 2 questions on what to try?

Comment: Understood @EdMorton, I got it from the first few times you commented on things I posted that you've got some issue with me. I'm reaching out about this while juggling work and a new baby - sorry that I'm not meeting your expectations.

Comment: I have no issue with you. I posted comments to help you clarify your questions to help you get good answers. I answered your first question and you ignored my advice for your 2nd question and so didn't get an answer you were happy with. You haven't provided an attempt for this question and so have accumulated downvotes and close votes and got less than ideal answers. I will try to remember to just ignore your questions going forward rather than risk offending you while trying to help you, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'|' '
FNR==NR{
    a[$2,$4,$5]=(a[$2,$4,$5]?a[$2,$4,$5] ORS:"")$0
    next
}
(($1,$2,$3) in a){
    print a[$1,$2,$3]
}' Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
175972|212946872418|quenchia@gmail.com|Anna|Balint
176046|255875|keion@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
176046|255875|keion112@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -f <(sed 's,|,|[^|]*|,' file2) file1
```

Returns

```
175972|212946872418|quenchia@gmail.com|Anna|Balint
176046|255875|keion@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
176046|255875|keion112@netscape.net|Charlene|Johnson
```

Explanations :

First command :

```
sed 's,|,|[^|]*|,' file2
```

Transforms file2 into a list of patterns to search in file 1 and returns :

```
89129090|[^|]*|Sadiq|Islam
212946872418|[^|]*|Anna|Balint
255875|[^|]*|Charlene|Johnson
89234902|[^|]*|Bob|Brown
09123789|[^|]*|Fabio|Vanetti
```

Second command :

```
grep -f <(command1) file1
```

Searchs patterns in file1